# Trying to launch an external editor from within a Go program

Tags: linux, editor, go

I am trying to figure out how to launch an external editor from within a Go program, wait for the user to close the editor, and then continue execution of the program. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076798/start-nano-as-a-subprocess-from-python-capture-input) SO answer, I currently have this code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    fpath := os.TempDir() + "/thetemporaryfile.txt"
    f, err := os.Create(fpath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("1")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f.Close()

    cmd := exec.Command("vim", fpath)
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("2")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error while editing. Error: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        log.Printf("Successfully edited.")
    }

}
```

When I run the program, I get this:

```
chris@DPC3:~/code/go/src/launcheditor$ go run launcheditor.go 
2012/08/23 10:50:37 Error while editing. Error: exit status 1
chris@DPC3:~/code/go/src/launcheditor$
```

I have also tried using `exec.Run()` instead of `exec.Start()`, but that doesn't seem to work either (though it doesn't fail at the same place).

I can get it to work if I use Gvim instead of Vim, but it refuses to work with both Vim and nano. I think it's related to Vim and nano running inside the terminal emulator instead of creating an external window.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently, you have to set `Stdin`, `Stdout` and `Stderr` on the `Cmd` object to `os.Std(in|out|err)`. Like this (assuming that the object is called `cmd`):

```
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
```

Credit for solving this goes to the guys on #go-nuts on freenode.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me but it has the disadvantage of opening another terminal (which will automatically close after edition) :

```
cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/xterm", "-e", "vim "+fpath)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in `cmd := exec.Command("vim", fpath)`, you're doing more or less:

```
$ PATH= vim foo.txt
bash: vim: No such file or directory
$
```

Shell uses the PATH environment variable, `exec.Command` does not. You have to lookup the `vim` binary and pass its full path to `exec.Command`. [exec.LookPath](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#LookPath) does that for you.

Comment: I tried, but it still doesn't work. Also, this cannot be the explanation as using just "gvim" works fine.

Comment: Checked. You're right. Don't know the reason yet. Looking into it.

Comment: For people finding this answer in the future, note that it is incorrect. From the docs: "If name contains no path separators, Command uses LookPath to resolve name to a complete path if possible." https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Command