# Why am I able to write to and read a tempfile even after closing it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, temporary-files, nano

I was experimenting with opening text editors from my python script and I noticed something that apparently contradicts my understanding of the documentation of [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html).

My experiment started out with Alex Martelli's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076863/3647970).
My code -

```
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess

f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+t', delete=True)
n = f.name
print('Does exist? : {0}'.format(os.path.exists(n)))
f.close()
print('Does exist? : {0}'.format(os.path.exists(n)))

subprocess.run(['nano', n])
with open(n) as f:
    print (f.read())

print('Does exist? : {0}'.format(os.path.exists(n)))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Does exist? : True
Does exist? : False
Hello from temp file.

Does exist? : True
```

In the code, I explicitly call `close` on the file object declared with `delete=True`, however even then I am able to write and read contents to it. I don't understand why this is happening. 
According to the docs-

> If delete is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it is closed.

If calling `close` deletes the file then I SHOULD NOT be able to write and then read it. But it displays the **correct** contents of the file that you enter when `nano` executes. And like a *tempfile*, the file is not visible in the directory where I opened the terminal and ran the script. 
What is even more strange is that `os.path.exists` works correctly for the first two times and *possibly incorrectly* for the third time.
Am I missing something here?

**Additional Experiment:**
If I run the following code then I can clearly see the file created. But that doesn't happen in the original code.

```
n = '.temp'
subprocess.run(['nano', n])
with open(n) as f:
    print (f.read())

print('Does exist? : {0}'.format(os.path.exists(n)))
```

Comment: From the docs "If delete is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it is closed."

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. The file is deleted as soon as it is closed.

Comment: @DYZ i am sorry, i forgot to add output. Edited now. There is NO error. The issue is that It SHOULD NOT work. Why is it working?

Comment: Ok. It's `nano` that creates your temp file again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets have a deeper look at your code.

First you create your temp file

```
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+t', delete=True)
n = f.name
print('Does exist? : {0}'.format(os.path.exists(n)))
```

and this output

```
Does exist? : True
```

so there is nothing to  worry about. Then in the next statements

```
f.close()
print('Does exist? : {0}'.format(os.path.exists(n)))
```

you are closing the file and actually the file gets deleted, because you are getting the following output:

```
Does exist? : False
```

Afterwards however you are recreating your file via

```
subprocess.run(['nano', n])
with open(n) as f:
    print (f.read())
```

so this is why afterwards the command

```
print('Does exist? : {0}'.format(os.path.exists(n)))
```

returns

```
Does exist? : True
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. But then why can't I actually see the file in the working directory? I have edited the question to add this information. I write only the last part of the code and there I can see that it creates the temp file. But why is it not visible in the original one?

Comment: @raj tempfile isn't creating the file in the working directory but in the temp file directory. So you will never see the file in the working directory.

Comment: @raj A temp file is opened in `/tmp`.

Comment: @DYZ Not necessarily, for example you can also change the path to the workingdirectory (linux: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068/how-do-i-find-the-temp-directory-in-linux windows: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/change-location-of-temp-files-folder-to-another/19f13330-dde1-404c-aa27-a76c0b450818) - but in most cases you are right

Comment: @DYZ yes, I just checked my /tmp folder and the files for which I had done `delete=False` were there. I just wanted to ask, if these files will be there forever? Also, since this answers my question and my question kind of looks silly now, should i leave it or delete it or accept @quant 's answer?

Comment: @raj You may leave the question here. Then, whenever someone has a similar question, I can simply mark his question as duplicated.

Comment: @quant okay. I will however accept your answer and maybe add one of my own making a summary of our comments if thats okay?

Comment: @ray For your point "and my question kind of looks silly now" ... You did not know that temp folders are created in the temp. directory - so I don't consider your question as silly or stupid.